# I need 100 amp service 700ft from the meter pole, what size wire do i need?

Tags: electrical

I need 100 amp power 700ft from meter pole. What size wire do I need?

Comment: What loads are you trying to power at the far end of this run?

Answer (score 6):

Edit: Given that the cost of aluminum wire will be deep into 4 digits, and that cost more than brand spanking new transformers, I'm going to put a transformer based solution at the bottom.

### My original answer - just fat wires.

Unfortunately the largest popular size, 4/0 aluminum, will give you a concerning 5.45% voltage drop at 80A.  We calculate voltage drop on 80% of service size, not 100%, because you're not allowed to *plan to* load a service beyond 80% continuous.  Look at the ratings of your consumer-tier service equipment, it says so right on it.

When we seek out a more sensible voltage drop, we find the following:

- 300 kcmil aluminum at 4.03%
- 350 kcmil aluminum at 3.59%
- 400 kcmil aluminum at 3.29%
- 500 kcmil aluminum at 2.81% (minimum for Canada)
- 600 kcmil aluminum at 2.52%

All of these based on 80A @ 700' @ 240V.
So now it boils down to your preference/tolerance, and what your supplier has a good price on. Some sizes are more popular than others.  One would be wasting their time and money at Home Depot, Lowes and Menards - you need to go to a real electrical supply to have any selection and any reasonable pricing.

### Neutral wire

Most of the time neutral has much less current than the other wires. 240V loads don't use it, and if you're using 120V heavily, it's spread across both poles and neutral carries only differential current. Could you downsize neutral? Sure... legally, NEC doesn't specify *any* wire size increases for voltage drop (although it has a practical max drop of around 10% due to other rules relating to fault clearing aka breakers being able to instant-trip on a dead short).  So you *could* go as small as 4/0 AWG (212 kcmil) on any conductor (contemplating a worst case of a 120V dead short), and neutral is one of those, so 4/0 neutral would be not unreasonable I think, assuming reasonably even phase loading.

### Ground wire

NEC says that when you enlarge a conductor for voltage drop, you must enlarge ground as well (again to ensure fault clearing). If the service wires were 1 foot long, the lives could be #2 (because it's a *service*, subpanel feeders need #1) and the grounds could be #6.  AWG is sized exponentially, so "4 AWG difference in size" is always a factor of 2.52. **So take the "kcmil" size of the hot wire you choose, divide by 2.52, and choose a ground wire with that kcmil or larger**. (this works out the same aluminum or copper). This will probably be down in the AWG sizes, so you need a kcmil to AWG chart:

- 1 AWG = 84 kcmil
- 1/0 AWG = 106 kcmil
- 2/0 AWG = 133 kcmil
- 3/0 AWG = 168 kcmil
- 4/0 AWG = 212 kcmil

### Aluminum, *of course*

This entire message assumes all-aluminum. Using copper at these sizes isn't even crazy.  Even if something special were needed at the Al wire terminations, it would be worth doing it for the *phantasmagorical* cost savings.  But nothing special is needed, actually - in fact, the lugs these wires will be landing on, at both ends, *are made of aluminum*. And for very good reason: sometimes you need to use copper (e.g. conduit size in old work), and aluminum lugs play nice with copper wire due to the *favorable* thermal expansion characteristics *when the aluminum is on the outside*.

Not knowing that in 1965 is reason #1 aluminum had a problem in the 70s. Reason #2, well, we didn't figure out *that* until the 2000s, and they weren't even looking at aluminum. *Screw torque matters* even on the small stuff, and as a testing rig taken to trade shows proved, master electricians can't hand-set torques any more accurately *than their spouses*. That was an eye-opener, and we kinda owe aluminum an apology lol.

### Transformers x2: Revenge of the Thrifty

First, let me describe what happens electrically.  You take 240V power from the utility.  It then goes through a main breaker (you really need this, unfortunately, to protect the transformers and wires).

Off the main breaker it feeds a [transformer](https://store.maddoxtransformer.com/products/1-phase-240x480-120-240?variant=45588998089&utm_term=&utm_campaign=Shopping%20%7C%20Performance%20Max%20-%20SG&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=8133699481&hsa_cam=15803302946&hsa_grp=&hsa_ad=&hsa_src=x&hsa_tgt=&hsa_kw=&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjaaX8sON-QIV0xmtBh0MHAq4EAQYAiABEgLVnPD_BwE), wired in reverse - power feeds the low (240V) side. This steps it up to 480V, 575V or 600V depending on cost/availability of the transformers.  Higher is better.

This goes to another transformer of the same type, and it is wired forward - the high voltage steps down to 120/240V.  This then feeds your house, and it is considered a service - so you bond neutral and ground in the panel, and have local ground rods.

This has a *mind-blowing* affect on wire size. Instead of carrying 100A of 240V, we are carrying 40A of 600V.

For instance 40A@600V only needs common, cheap, commodity #2 AWG aluminum wire to achieve a good 2.74% voltage drop.  So that drops the cost of wire to under $1000.

See what I mean about "pays for the transformers"?  This... this is why AC won the War of the Currents.

50A @ 480V requires #1 AWG to get 3.51% drop, 1/0 AWG to get 3.04% drop, or 2/0 AWG to get great 2.37% drop.  Again all aluminum.

What's more, the transformers have taps to allow you to "bump" the voltage slightly to compensate for drop.

Now the only thing to talk about is the fairly hazardous 480 or 600 volts between the transformers.  It's really best for that to be a single conduit that runs straight between the transformer enclosures with no interruptions. No extra equipment, no boxes, no disconnects, etc. -- nothing for idiots to open up expecting to find normal old 120V-to-ground. I would put the transformers on pads, with the conduit coming up through the pad right into the transformer enclosure.  "Danger 600V" stickers on it, and no one ever has a reason to open up a transformer enclosure. Just leave it alone.

Or if running a pole line, put the transformer up on the pole where no one *can* get to it. In that case you really need the ground wire, set much higher on the pole - that is to catch lightning.

Only 2 wires need be run. The 700' run between transformers cannot use a neutral, and arguably doesn't even need a ground wire, since it is fully isolated from 120/240V at both ends.  Talk to your AHJ about whether they will permit this solution.

Comment: Note that you'll need a fuse in the upstream (closest to the utility) transformer's secondary circuit -- this can be simply in a fuse block in the transformer enclosure though

Answer (score -2):

You are getting into some very large and expensive copper wire, guessing probably in the $15 to $20 per foot range maybe even high. Seriously consider having the Edison (power supplier) place a transformer at the target end. Another approach is to purchase transformers and boost the voltage up then back down at the target, depending on the voltage the wire size may be adjusted appropriately.

To wire it directly using A 400 MCM copper conductor will limit the voltage drop to less then or equal to 3% supplying 100 amps for 700 feet assuming a 240 volt system. If I understand the NEC correctly and I am making some assumptions conductors can only be loaded to 80% of their rated capacity therefore 100 x 80% = 80 amps.

Note:  If you actually need the full 100 amps then you would need to use a wire with a rating of 125 amps or greater, this is calculated as 125 x 80% = 100 amps. Again assuming a 240V system you will need a 600 MCM copper conductor to keep the voltage at 3% or less at 125 amps for 700 feet. You can use aluminum wire which is less costly but larger size will be needed and you will need to redo all the calculations.

Before doing any of this check with your local inspector and see if it will be approved.

Comment: Aluminum is just about guaranteed to be allowed here, and a lot cheaper than copper. Also the 80% rule is pretty firm after the main panel, but does not necessarily apply for a service feed. Hopefully Ed Beal or ThreePhaseEel or Harper can provide specifics.

Comment: It would be highly foolish to use copper in such an application. The power company doesn't. Further, on each end the wires will land on lugs which are made of aluminum. (Because, when the lug body is aluminum and the wire is copper, differing thermal expansion works in its favor, thus it plays well with both Cu and Al.) Anything you've heard about aluminum wire being bad is ... well, out of context.

Comment: It is insanity to even contemplate copper here.

Comment: Just go for silver wire if trying to demonstrate how little cost impacts your life, and for *best* conductivity above 138 °K (while seething with envy at the folks who laugh at the cost of keeping their powerline filled with liquid nitrogen.) The rest of us will use aluminum.